# Does "conda clean --all" affect my already existing conda enviroments?

Tags: anaconda

I created a new conda enviroment, but when I tried to install gdal via

```
conda install -c anaconda gdal
```

I got a CondaVerificationError. Following [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureNotebooks/issues/88) post I should do something like

```
conda clean --all
```

As far as I know this will delete all cached packages stored in tarballs.
Is this having any effect on my already existing other enviroments? Or is the only pupose of these balls that you don't have to download the same packages more than one time and when a new enviroment wants to install a package, already existing as tarball, then it uses the tarball to unzip the package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: No it doesn't...